# Rails form params issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm constructing some data to send over jQuery's $.post, the data that I send looks like this:

```
authenticity_token: LxHlgi1WU8o0DtaNuiQOit/e+HlGR2plVcToHUAhA6I=
crews[0][boat_id]: 2
crews[0][crew][]: 10
end_time: 1280408400
start_time: 1280404800
```

Which is from jQuery converting the data object which is prepared by:

- creating an array [] for each 'crew' found in the DOM, called crews.
- Then I cycle over the crews in the DOM, create an object and store its boat ID
- then I create another array for its a crews list of members, which is then added into the crew's object and pushed onto the 'crews' array. (The JS is a bit long, can post if needed)

Then in my controller I have:

```
def create
  @outing = Outing.create(
    :club => current_user.club,
    :title => 'Outing',
    :start_time => Time.at(params[:start_time].to_i),
    :end_time => Time.at(params[:end_time].to_i)
  )
  @outing.save

  Rails.logger.debug(params[:crews].inspect)
  params[:crews].each_with_index do |crew,i|
    Rails.logger.debug(crew.inspect)

    @crew = Crew.create(
      :boat_id => crew[:boat_id].to_i,
      :outing_id => @outing.id
    )
    @crew.save

    crew[:crew].each do |c|
      @cu = CrewUsers.create(
        :crew_id => @crew.id,
        :user_id => c.to_i
      )
    end
  end

  render :nothing => true    
end
```

The two inspect statements print something like this:

```
{"0"=>{"crew"=>["10"], "boat_id"=>"2"}}
["0", {"crew"=>["10"], "boat_id"=>"2"}]
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError (Symbol as array index):
```

To me, crews shouldn't be an indexed array, and that's where the issue is. But I could also be totally wrong. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `params[:crews]` is a `Hash`, but you're trying to use it as if it's an `Array`. Hashes don't have indexes, per se, but rather keys.

You could get the result you're looking for if you use [`Hash#each_pair`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002864) (or [`Hash#each_value`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002862) if you don't need keys) instead of `each_with_index`:

```
params[:crews].each_pair do |i, crew| # note that the block parameters are reversed
  ...
end
```

To demonstrate:

```
hash = {"0"=>{"crew"=>["10"], "boat_id"=>"2"}}
hash.each_pair do |i, crew|
  puts crew.inspect
end
#=> {"crew"=>["10"], "boat_id"=>"2"}
```

Note that you will still have an issue looking for `crew[:boat_id]`, because your keys are strings and not symbols.

Comment: You're a bloody star, thank you! I had a feeling it was something wrong with that.
Interestingly, I wonder why the `crew` sub-array wasn't parsed as a Hash by jQuery/Rails